# SQL Injection via Rest API Body

Tags: mysql, sql, security, sql-injection

I'm currently checking if my Rest API is vulnerable to an SQL Injection but I'm confused on the process.

My API accepts JSON, then sends the requests to a Mysql database. I've tried sending strings that *should* lead to SQL injection like `' OR 'x'='x`, but rather than being executed they're being sent to the server as strings, which I suppose means they're not a problem.

I'm now doing some more intensive testing with Postman, however if I try to add strings to my parameters such as :

```
{
   "name": "test" OR 1 = 1 -- "
}
```

Postman will just inform me the JSON syntax is incorrect and even if I do send it, I'll get an "Invalid JSON" response without it even getting to my Rest API.

Is this a good or bad thing? How do I actually go about testing my API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postman right, your JSON is corrupted. You should escape double quotes in field name or value, it is special symbol in JSON.

Your query should looks like:

```
{
   "name": "test\" OR 1 = 1 -- "
}
```

Read more about special chars in JSON: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Thank you! Would've never thought about that.